# XSLT copy parent element tree inside child template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Well, for example I have an XML:

```
<ProcessPurchaseOrder >
    <PurchaseOrderLine>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference2">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>100</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference3">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>ru</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <Item>
            <CustomerItemID>
                <ID>00126</ID>
            </CustomerItemID>
        </Item>
    </PurchaseOrderLine>
    <PurchaseOrderLine>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference2">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>200</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference3">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>ru</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <Item>
            <CustomerItemID>
                <ID>123122</ID>
            </CustomerItemID>
        </Item>
    </PurchaseOrderLine>
</ProcessPurchaseOrder>
```

and part of XSLT:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="*:PurchaseOrderLine">
    <xsl:variable name="ArtNr" select="*:Item/*:CustomerItemID/*:ID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="WepNr" select="/*/DbResponse/ResultSet/Row[Cell[@name='ARTNR']=$ArtNr][Cell[@name='WEANR']=$WeaNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$WepNr!=''">
            <xsl:for-each select="$WepNr">
                <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="$WepNr/current()"/></LineNumber>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For every `$WepNr` value I want to copy whole `<PurchaseOrderLine>` and insert `<LineNumber>` with current `WepNr` value.

So, for example: if `$WepNr` for 1st PurchaseOrderLine returns: 16; 26 result will be:

```
<ProcessPurchaseOrder >
    <PurchaseOrderLine>
    <!-- wepnr[1] = 16 -->
    <LineNumber>16</LineNumber>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference2">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>100</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference3">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>ru</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <Item>
            <CustomerItemID>
                <ID>00126</ID>
            </CustomerItemID>
        </Item>
    </PurchaseOrderLine>
    <PurchaseOrderLine>
    <!-- copied PurchaseOrderLine with wepnr[2]=26 -->
    <LineNumber>26</LineNumber>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference2">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>100</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <DocumentReference type="sendersReference3">
            <DocumentID>
                <ID>ru</ID>
            </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <Item>
            <CustomerItemID>
                <ID>00126</ID>
            </CustomerItemID>
        </Item>
    </PurchaseOrderLine>

    <!-- here is 2nd PurchaseOrderLine>
    <!-- ... -->

</ProcessPurchaseOrder>
```

Is it possible?

**UPD**:
DBresponse XML part

```
<DbResponse>
   <ResultSet>
      <Row>
         <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">1909123</Cell>
         <Cell name="ARTNR" type="VARCHAR2">00126</Cell>
         <Cell name="WEPNR" type="VARCHAR2">1</Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
         <Cell name="WEANR" type="VARCHAR2">1909123</Cell>
         <Cell name="ARTNR" type="VARCHAR2">00126</Cell>
         <Cell name="WEPNR" type="VARCHAR2">16</Cell>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</DbResponse>
```

It just means that `WepNr` could return multiple values: like "`1 16`" in this case

Comment: Please show us the input sample with elements you are trying to select in `/*/DbResponse/ResultSet/Row[Cell[@name='ARTNR']=$ArtNr][Cell[@name='WEANR']=$WeaNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen question was updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of

```
 <xsl:for-each select="*:PurchaseOrderLine">
    <xsl:variable name="ArtNr" select="*:Item/*:CustomerItemID/*:ID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="WepNr" select="/*/DbResponse/ResultSet/Row[Cell[@name='ARTNR']=$ArtNr][Cell[@name='WEANR']=$WeaNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$WepNr!=''">
            <xsl:for-each select="$WepNr">
                <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="$WepNr/current()"/></LineNumber>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

you rather want:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="*:PurchaseOrderLine"/>
```

and then at the top level

```
 <xsl:key name="row-by-wepnr" 
   match="DbResponse/ResultSet/Row"
   use="Cell[@name='ARTNR']"/>


 <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrderLine">
   <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
   <xsl:variable name="wepNrs" select="key('row-by-wepnr', *:Item/*:CustomerItemID/*:ID)[Cell[@name='WEANR']=$WeaNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$wepNrs">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$this" mode="add-wep">
       <xsl:with-param name="wep" select="current()"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrderLine" mode="add-wep">
    <xsl:param name="wep"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="$wep"/></LineNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That assumes that `$WearNr` is a global param or variable, otherwise you would need to pass that value on e.g.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="*:PurchaseOrderLine">
   <xsl:with-param name"WearNr" select="$WearNr"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
```

and

```
 <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrderLine">
   <xsl:param name="$WearNr"/>
   <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
   <xsl:variable name="wepNrs" select="key('row-by-wepnr', *:Item/*:CustomerItemID/*:ID)[Cell[@name='WEANR']=$WeaNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$wepNrs">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$this" mode="add-wep">
       <xsl:with-param name="wep" select="current()"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrderLine" mode="add-wep">
    <xsl:param name="wep"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="$wep"/></LineNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

All untested of course, you would better supply minimal but complete code sample allowing us to write testable code.